# Leetcode Problem: Sort the Matrix Diagonally | Help (but not too much)

Tags: python, matrix, diagonal

**Problem:**

A matrix diagonal is a diagonal line of cells starting from some cell in either the topmost row or leftmost column and going in the bottom-right direction until reaching the matrix's end. For example, the matrix diagonal starting from mat[2][0], where mat is a 6 x 3 matrix, includes cells mat[2][0], mat[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBJg2.png), and mat[4][2].

Given an m x n matrix mat of integers, sort each matrix diagonal in ascending order and return the resulting matrix.
[image]

**My Problem:**

I figured out, that the **difference** of row and col of the diagonal cells is the same for one specific diagonal line. For example the difference of line 3,2,1 (mat[0][0]... mat[i][i]) is obviously 0, beyond that its -1, -2 etc...

I can extract all cells with the difference < 0.. but that's not helpful, since i want the order of the diagonal cells/lines

```
lst = [[3,3,1,1],[2,2,1,2],[1,1,1,2]]
new_list = []

for i in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(len(lst[0])):
        if i-j < 0:
           new_list.append(lst[i][j])

print(new_list)
output -> [3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

So far so good, i cant think of a code that prioritises the specific difference. I want all -1 cells first, then -2 cells ... etc. I could write a lot of if-statements, but that's not the optimal solution...
I'm pretty much stuck here. Pls help me with a few fresh ideas. Pls don't tell me the complete solution. Just push me into the right direction, appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to identify each position with a diagonal ID.  Then sort the flattened values by diagonal-ID/value and place them back in a resulting matrix:

```
def sortDiag(M):
    rows,cols = len(M),len(M[0])        # matrix dimensions
    diags     = range(rows + cols - 1)  # diagonal identifiers
    diagNo    = [ (d,r,c) for r in range(rows)
                          for c,d in enumerate(diags[-cols-r::][:cols]) ]
    diagVal   = [ (d,M[r][c]) for d,r,c in diagNo ] # values per diagonal
    result    = [[None]*cols for _ in range(rows)]
    for (_,v),(_,r,c) in zip(sorted(diagVal),sorted(diagNo)):
        result[r][c] = v  # assign position with sorted value
    return result
```

output:

```
M = [[3,3,1,1],[2,2,1,2],[1,1,1,2]]
print(*M,sep="\n")

[3, 3, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 2]

print(*sortDiag(M),sep="\n")

[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 2, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 3]
```

In this example, the diagonal identifiers are numbers from 0 to 5 and the coordinate list in `diagNo` corresponds to the following assignments:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

By mapping the sorted positions (per diagonal) with the sorted values (per diagonal) we can assign the sorted values to the positions corresponding to each diagonal.